# How to parse a list of url to get "Link" and "id" out using xml in R

Tags: r, xml, xml2

```
[1] "<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"itemWithRetweets\" link=\"http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416\" id=\"1002221842894012416\">\n  <author>Charlie Kirk</author>\n  <date>2018-05-31T12:14:42-04:00</date>\n  <attachments/>\n  <estimated_retweets>30</estimated_retweets>\n  <screenName>charliekirk11</screenName>\n  <avatarUrl>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/993982887635685377/4CEEsYDS_normal.jpg</avatarUrl>\n  <language>en</language>\n  <location>\n    <country>US</country>\n    <locationString>Chicago, Illinois</locationString>\n  </location>\n</item>"
[2] "<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"itemWithRetweets\" link=\"http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416\" id=\"1002221842894012416\">\n  <author>Charlie Kirk</author>\n  <date>2018-05-31T12:14:42-04:00</date>\n  <attachments/>\n  <estimated_retweets>30</estimated_retweets>\n  <screenName>charliekirk11</screenName>\n  <avatarUrl>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/993982887635685377/4CEEsYDS_normal.jpg</avatarUrl>\n  <language>en</language>\n  <location>\n    <country>US</country>\n    <locationString>Chicago, Illinois</locationString>\n  </location>\n</item>"
[3] "<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"itemWithRetweets\" link=\"http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416\" id=\"1002221842894012416\">\n  <author>Charlie Kirk</author>\n  <date>2018-05-31T12:14:42-04:00</date>\n  <attachments/>\n  <estimated_retweets>30</estimated_retweets>\n  <screenName>charliekirk11</screenName>\n  <avatarUrl>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/993982887635685377/4CEEsYDS_normal.jpg</avatarUrl>\n  <language>en</language>\n  <location>\n    <country>US</country>\n    <locationString>Chicago, Illinois</locationString>\n  </location>\n</item>"
```

I have a list of urls and would like to grab only "link" and "id" out. I have tried xml_attr(x, "link) and xml_attr(x, "id") but it does not seem to work for a list.

Comment: Did you iterate through list? Please show full attempted code block with all `library` lines.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using [`purrr`](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package from the tidyverse.

Basically, `map` function allows you to iterate trough a list, apply a function and get back a list. Here I parsed the xml and tidy the value in a tibble (data.frame like) format. `map_dfr` will transform directly the resulting list a a table format by row binding.

```r
xml_text <- list("<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"itemWithRetweets\" link=\"http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416\" id=\"1002221842894012416\">\n  <author>Charlie Kirk</author>\n  <date>2018-05-31T12:14:42-04:00</date>\n  <attachments/>\n  <estimated_retweets>30</estimated_retweets>\n  <screenName>charliekirk11</screenName>\n  <avatarUrl>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/993982887635685377/4CEEsYDS_normal.jpg</avatarUrl>\n  <language>en</language>\n  <location>\n    <country>US</country>\n    <locationString>Chicago, Illinois</locationString>\n  </location>\n</item>",
"<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"itemWithRetweets\" link=\"http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416\" id=\"1002221842894012416\">\n  <author>Charlie Kirk</author>\n  <date>2018-05-31T12:14:42-04:00</date>\n  <attachments/>\n  <estimated_retweets>30</estimated_retweets>\n  <screenName>charliekirk11</screenName>\n  <avatarUrl>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/993982887635685377/4CEEsYDS_normal.jpg</avatarUrl>\n  <language>en</language>\n  <location>\n    <country>US</country>\n    <locationString>Chicago, Illinois</locationString>\n  </location>\n</item>",
"<item xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"itemWithRetweets\" link=\"http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416\" id=\"1002221842894012416\">\n  <author>Charlie Kirk</author>\n  <date>2018-05-31T12:14:42-04:00</date>\n  <attachments/>\n  <estimated_retweets>30</estimated_retweets>\n  <screenName>charliekirk11</screenName>\n  <avatarUrl>http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/993982887635685377/4CEEsYDS_normal.jpg</avatarUrl>\n  <language>en</language>\n  <location>\n    <country>US</country>\n    <locationString>Chicago, Illinois</locationString>\n  </location>\n</item>")

library(xml2)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
xml_text %>% 
  map_dfr(~ {
    content <- read_xml(.x)
    tibble(
      link = xml_attr(content, "link"),
      id = xml_attr(content, "id")
    )
  })
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   link                                                          id        
#>   <chr>                                                         <chr>     
#> 1 http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416 100222184~
#> 2 http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416 100222184~
#> 3 http://twitter.com/charliekirk11/statuses/1002221842894012416 100222184~
```

Created on 2018-06-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).